# Trying to load my seed data before cucumber tests in Rails3 / Capybara with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I have some seed data (for price ranges) that is the same in prod, dev, test and doesn't change. I need that data in my test db to run my cuke tests.

I am load my seed data into test DB before the scenario loads, but it's failing.

I have the following in my features/support/env.rb file

```
# from http://www.andhapp.com/blog/2009/11/07/using-factory_girl-with-cucumber/
Before do
    require 'factory_girl_rails'
    # Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../spec/factories/*.rb')).each {|f| require f }
    Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../db/seeds.rb')).each {|f| require f }
end
```

Which loads the following file:

```
# wipe out all previous data
Price.delete_all #is there a factory way of doing this?
# set defaults
Factory.define :price do |price|
  price.id                  1
  price.price_range         "$100"
end

# insert seed data
@price = Factory(:price, :id => 1, :price_range => "$100 - $500")
@price = Factory(:price, :id => 2, :price_range => "$500 - $1,000")
@price = Factory(:price, :id => 3, :price_range => "$1,000 - $1,000")
@price = Factory(:price, :id => 4, :price_range => "$10,000 - $100,000")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Factory already defined: price (Factory::DuplicateDefinitionError)
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:61:in `define'
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rails_testing/feedbackd/features/support/../../db/seeds.rb:16
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rails_testing/feedbackd/features/support/env.rb:92
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rails_testing/feedbackd/features/support/env.rb:92:in `each'
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rails_testing/feedbackd/features/support/env.rb:92:in `Before'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `Factory.define :price` once, and I would probably not put it in the file that it's in right now.  Do you have a factories folder?  It usually lives in spec/factories.  In there I would create the file price.rb, and define your factory once, there.  factory_girl should automatically load all of those definitions up for you once.

If you're using Rails3 and you have factory_girl_rails in your Gemfile, then you don't even need that `require 'factory_girl_rails'`, it does it for you.

Also if you have a new-ish version of cucumber the installer should automatically have added this section for you in env.rb:

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end
```

DatabaseCleaner is a good way to do the truncation instead of using your `Price.delete_all`

The last thing is seeds.rb - It's a good concept and something very similar to what we do in one of our apps at work.

But keep in mind, everything in the `features/support` directory is automatically required by cucumber, so you don't need to have that Dir.glob nonsense.

With factory_girl we don't use the default rails seeds file because it's not really applicable (in our opinion).

I would just add a file named anything (ours is named `db_setup.rb`) that looks something like this:

```
Before do
  # Truncates the DB before each Scenario,
  # make sure you've added database_cleaner to your Gemfile.
  DatabaseCleaner.clean

  Factory(:price, :attr1 => 'blah'...)
  # More factories here etc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at hooks:

https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

You can use tagged hooks to only load up specific seed data, much like you would only execute specific tags in cucumber.

You can also employ the heavy handed rails way and do a rake db:test:clone.